# Integration of positive function over$\mathbb R$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f$ be a continuous integrable function of $\mathbb R$ such that either $f(x)>0$ or $f(x)+f(x+1)>0$ for all real numbers. Then  $ \int_{- \infty}^{\infty}f(x) >0.$

My attempt let $f(x)= e^x$ this is positive function. Can we say that this function is integrable on $\mathbb R.$

Comment: I think your question is incomplete..Do yo want prove or disprove , it's unclear.

Comment: I am thinking that above statement is incorrect .So I am trying to produce a counter example .

Comment: But $e^x$ will not be counter example because the integration is $\infty$ , which may be considered as positive .

Comment: If not then try to find a counterexample or proof of statement .

Comment: Your counterexample is invalid. On one hand, $e^x$ is not Riemann integrable over the whole real line, but $f$ is required to be integrable in your question. On the other hand, $e^x$ is Lebesgue integrable over $\mathbb R$, but the integral is $+\infty$, which is positive.

Answer (score 0):

First of all,let's write that integral like this:
$\underset{a \to \infty}{\lim} \int_{-a}^{a} f(x)dx$.Now, if $f$ is odd,the integral is equal to 0 which it's not greater than 0. So the function must to be even to get something from that inequality.If we take away that limit for a second,we can say:
If $f$ is even we know that $\int_{-a}^{a} f(x)dx=2\int_{0}^{a} f(x)dx>0 \Leftrightarrow \int_{0}^{a} f(x)dx>0$

But at the same time $\int_{-a}^{0} f(x)dx=\int_{0}^{a} f(x)dx$(substitute x=-t). And that gives us that $\int_{-a}^{0}f(x)dx>0$

By adding those two positive integrals we get that $\int_{-a}^{a} f(x)dx>0$. But I don't know what to say when  $a$ is going to infinty because as said in the comments,maybe this is incorrect from the beginning.

Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong anywhere.

Comment: Your explanation seems right but how can we apply this explanation to given problem . How one can solve above problem . May I say that if this integral is positive over every [-a,a]  interval then this also holds for when a is going to infinity.

Comment: I just wanted to show you that the problem is not necessarily wrong.If $f(x)>0 \Rightarrow \displaystyle \int f(x)>0$. And as you mentioned,the inequality holds when $a$ is going to infinity.

Comment: It means proof must exists . Can someone prove it. Thanks in advance